# sails lift causes error ENOENT (No such file or Directory)

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Im trying to launch this project https://github.com/lucj/sails-oauth2-api to learn from it however im having trouble getting it to work.

I installed the prerequisites with:

npm install

in the terminal at the project directory

when i do:

```
strace -f -e trace=process sails lift
```

it gives me the following debugging output.

```
    execve("/usr/bin/sails", ["sails", "lift"], [/* 64 vars */]) = 0
    arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f4017319740) = 0
    execve("/usr/local/sbin/node", ["node", "/usr/bin/sails", "lift"], [/* 64 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    execve("/usr/local/bin/node", ["node", "/usr/bin/sails", "lift"], [/* 64 vars */]) = -1     ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    execve("/usr/sbin/node", ["node", "/usr/bin/sails", "lift"], [/* 64 vars */]) = -1     ENOENT (No such file or directory)    
    execve("/usr/bin/node", ["node", "/usr/bin/sails", "lift"], [/* 64 vars */]) = 0
    arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f204315b780) = 0
    clone(child_stack=0x7f2043172f70,         flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CL    ONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f20431739d0, tls=0x7f2043173700, child_tidptr=0x7f20431739d0) = 5575
    Process 5575 attached
    [pid  5574] clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,     child_tidptr=0x7f204315ba50) = 5576
    Process 5576 attached
    [pid  5576] execve("/usr/bin/nodejs", ["/usr/bin/nodejs", "/home/vern/sails-oauth2-    api-deve"..., "default", "--gdsrc=/home/vern/sails-oauth2-"..., "--environment=development", "--baseurl=http://localhost:1337", "--signalpath=/___signal"],     [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
    [pid  5576] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fc1da6b1780) = 0
    [pid  5576] clone(child_stack=0x7fc1da6c8f70,     flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CL    ONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fc1da6c99d0,     tls=0x7fc1da6c9700, child_tidptr=0x7fc1da6c99d0) = 5577
    Process 5577 attached
[pid  5574] clone(child_stack=0x7f2041b39f70, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CL    ONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f2041b3a9d0, tls=0x7f2041b3a700, child_tidptr=0x7f2041b3a9d0) = 5578
    [pid  5574] clone(child_stack=0x7f2041338f70,     flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CL    ONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f20413399d0, tls=0x7f2041339700, child_tidptr=0x7f20413399d0) = 5579
    [pid  5574] clone(child_stack=0x7f2040b37f70,     flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CL    ONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f2040b389d0,     tls=0x7f2040b38700, child_tidptr=0x7f2040b389d0) = 5580
    Process 5580 attached
    Process 5579 attached
    Process 5578 attached
    [pid  5574] clone(child_stack=0x7f203bffef70,     flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CL    ONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f203bfff9d0,     tls=0x7f203bfff700, child_tidptr=0x7f203bfff9d0) = 5581
    Process 5581 attached
    trustedTestClient already exists
    - client_id: NC2OKCDJAI
    - client_secret: JNRL6Rlw6NDPEXPBFgFRkQ4EybQYFu
    - redirectURI: http://localhost:1338
    untrustedTestClient already exists
    - client_id: TR5U2NKLJO
    - client_secret: hq0Qgm2NpQ6KRbd91Dwy7Ao1Jlcv6E
    - redirectURI: http://localhost:1339
    info: 
    info: 
    info:    Sails.js           <|
    info:    v0.9.11              |\
    info:                       /|.\
    info:                      / || \
    info:                    ,'  |'  \
    info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
    info:                 `--'-------' 
    info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
    info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
    info: 
    info: Server lifted in `/home/vern/sails-oauth2-api-develop`
    info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:1337
    info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.

    debug: --------------------------------------------------------
    debug: :: Fri Jun 13 2014 05:00:49 GMT-0700 (PDT)
    debug: 
    debug: Environment  : development
    debug: Port     : 1337
    debug: --------------------------------------------------------
    debug: Lowering sails...
    [pid  5576] --- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=5574, si_uid=1000} ---
    [pid  5577] +++ killed by SIGHUP +++

    events.js:72
            throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
                  ^
    Error: ENOENT, open 'logs/application.log'
    [pid  5579] _exit(0)                    = ?
    [pid  5580] _exit(0)                    = ?
    [pid  5581] _exit(0)                    = ?
    [pid  5580] +++ exited with 0 +++
    [pid  5581] +++ exited with 0 +++
    [pid  5579] +++ exited with 0 +++
    [pid  5576] +++ killed by SIGHUP +++
    [pid  5574] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=5576, si_status=SIGHUP, si_utime=86, si_stime=26} ---
    [pid  5578] _exit(0)                    = ?
    [pid  5574] exit_group(8)               = ?
    [pid  5575] +++ exited with 8 +++
    [pid  5578] +++ exited with 8 +++
    +++ exited with 8 +++
```

The top 6 lines mean something but i dont know what it means and how i need to fix it. I have a selfmade project that works perfectly when i use sails lift.

P.S. The project supposedly created 2 clients which i can find back in the debug output but the application crashes later on.

So its something with this project that causes the problem but what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says `Error: ENOENT, open 'logs/application.log'`.
This means it's trying to open logs/application.log but that it doesn't exist. Try creating the file and lifting again:

`mkdir logs && cd $_ && touch application.log && cd .. && sails lift`

Comment: Thanks, didnt know the answer would be this simple, did what u told me and it worked out!